# How to push element in array in a certain structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, chart.js, push

I need to `push` element in an `array` inside `loop` in a certain structure but not sure how to do that. This is my code

```
var data={appNamesLables,datasets: [] };

var backgroundColorSGreen='#318CE7'
var backgroundColorRed='#FF8C00'
var backgroundColorYellow='#F49AC2'
var lebel1='Green'
var lebel2='Red'
var lebel3='Yellow'

for (let i = 0; i < appNamesLables.length; i++)
{
  var strToMatch=appNamesLables[i]
  //@ts-ignore
  const matches = Object.values(products).filter(s =>s.Name.toString().includes(strToMatch)); 
var green = matches.reduce(function (n, comp) {
     //@ts-ignore
    return n + parseInt(comp.statusGreen);
  }, 0);

var red = matches.reduce(function (n, comp) {
    //@ts-ignore
   return n + parseInt(comp.statusRed);
 }, 0);

 var yellow = matches.reduce(function (n, comp) {
  //@ts-ignore
 return n + parseInt(comp.statusYellow);
}, 0);


  //Here I need to push element
  data.datasets.push()
  data.datasets.push()
  data.datasets.push()
}
```

This structure I am looking for

```
datasets: [
{
  label: "Green",
  backgroundColor:  '#318CE7',
  data: [60, 90, 120, 60, 90, 445, 4344, 4565, 3344, 444,567]
},
{
  label: "Yellow",
  backgroundColor: '#F49AC2',
  data: [40, 60, 80, 40, 60, 4567, 4343, 566, 454, 34,567]
},
{
 label: "Red",
 backgroundColor: '#FF8C00',
 data: [20, 30, 40, 20, 30, 345, 231, 907, 4332, 567,203],
},
],
```

I need to push all `red` in a single array and same for `green` and `yellow`. Everytime loop running I am getting single count for `data:[]` for each color. Yellow, Red and variables returns the `number`. How can I do that?

Comment: How does the input looks like ?

Comment: What is the end result you need?

Comment: @TigranAbrahamyan - inputs are `numbers` only

Comment: @BiswaBhusan - End result is getting the given structure in data defined in first `line`

Comment: No, I was asking is it a JSON that needed to be restructured and if it is JSON then please add it

Comment: Please attach a sample for `appNamesLabel` and what you  are actually getting.

Comment: @BiswaBhusan - I need this data for chart.js dataset. I need in a way so that I can bind it to chart. Same as give output.

Comment: @R15: can you please create some demo on jsfiddle or somewhere so that it becomes easier to understand?

Comment: @sabbir.alam - yellow, green and red are numbers.

Comment: Yeah I got that but what is a `products` object please define

Comment: @BiswaBhusan - Products is for fetching the numbers only that's all.

Comment: @R15 that is, you need the end result like this?
const result = [60, 90, 120, 60, 90, 445, 4344, 4565, 3344, 444, 567, 40, 60, 80, 40, 60, 4567, 4343, 566, 454, 34, 567, 20, 30, 40, 20, 30, 345, 231, 907, 4332, 567, 203];

Comment: @TigranAbrahamyan - yes, but I need bg color and label too.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an empty array as initial value for reduce method instead of 0 and instead of adding the value you can insert the value into the array and return that array.

```
var data={appNamesLables,datasets: [] };

var backgroundColorSGreen='#318CE7'
var backgroundColorRed='#FF8C00'
var backgroundColorYellow='#F49AC2'
var lebel1='Green'
var lebel2='Red'
var lebel3='Yellow'

for (let i = 0; i < appNamesLables.length; i++)
{
  var strToMatch=appNamesLables[i]
  //@ts-ignore
  const matches = Object.values(products).filter(s =>s.Name.toString().includes(strToMatch)); 
var green = matches.reduce(function (n, comp) {
     //@ts-ignore
    return [...n, parseInt(comp.statusGreen)];
  }, []);

var red = matches.reduce(function (n, comp) {
    //@ts-ignore
   return [...n, parseInt(comp.statusRed)];
 }, []);

 var yellow = matches.reduce(function (n, comp) {
  //@ts-ignore
 return [...n, parseInt(comp.statusYellow)];
}, []);


}

//Here I need to push element
  data.datasets.push({
     label: label1,
     backgroundColor: backgroundColorSGreen,
     data: green,
  })

  data.datasets.push({
     labe: label2, 
     backgroundColor: backgroundColorRed, 
     data: red })

  data.datasets.push({
     labe: label3, 
     backgroundColor: backgroundColorYellow, 
     data: yellow 
  })
```

Instead of reduce you can use map as well like this,

```
var green = matches.map(item => item.statusGreen);
var red = matches.map(item => item.statusRed);
var yellow = matches.map(item => item.statusYellow);
```

This will be much cleaner.

Comment: You are pushing bg color and label many times but both I need only 3 places. Can't that be done outside loop. I need to count+ of every field that why not using map. I just not need those values. Every iteration has multiple records. So need to add those values.

Comment: Yes I have just updated the code according to your structure. If you want to do that outside of the loop you need to move `data.datasets.push({})` part outside of the loop for 3 colors. I am updating the code.

Comment: Not getting 3 arrays inside datasets. I am just getting all records in a row.

Comment: Without your sample data it is impossible for us to give you a solution . Please provide a sample for `appNamesLables` and `products`. Or create a js fiddle to reproduce the issue and share the link.